# How to get a mac address

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-programming, ip, mac-address

Can I get a MAC address that are connected to my site.

this code get mac address host and return error permission.

```
  String macadress = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            OperationalStatus ot = nic.OperationalStatus;
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macadress = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macadress;
```

now how can get mac address users???

2.
how can get ip users???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get the user's MAC address in the way that you want. It's my understanding that MAC addresses are stripped from packets when they leave your local network.

You can *try* to get the user's address from `Request.UserHostAddress`. However if you are behind a load balancer or content distribution network then you might want to try looking in `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]` first - this is where the users original IP address will often be written when the request is forwarded on by something.

The approach I'll usually take is to try something along the lines of:

```
var address = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
    address = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

The last project I worked on, we actually logged both, in case the forwarded for header had been faked.

Comment: MAC addresses are a feature of the _Local_ Area Network - the MAC address you would see in a packet would be from your router, because that is the thing in your LAN that forwarded that packet to you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the MAC address from the request, however, you can get the IP with `Request.UserHostAddress`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the MAC address of the end-user's machine.

You can get the user's public IP address using `Request.UserHostAddress`.

Note the IP address this will not be unique per-user.
If multiple users are behind the same proxy or are on a corporate network, they will usually share the same address.
You can check the [`X-Forwarded-For` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) to get a little more information.
Note that this header can be chained or faked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
        {
            string macAddress = string.Empty;
            System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
            pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
            pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
             pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pProcess.Start();
            string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
            if (substrings.Length >= 8)
            {
              macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2)) + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6] + "-" + substrings[7] + "-" +
                      substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
                return macAddress;
            }

            else
            {
                return "not found";
            }
        }
```